# Get CSS content from a rule using regex

Tags: css, regex

For example, I have a stylesheet:

```
.foo {
 background-color: #fff;
}

.bar {
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

What regex could I use to get `background-color: #fff;` from `.foo`?

UPD: There could be anything in `.foo` so no need to hard code `background-color`

Comment: Do you want to look at just one specific stylesheet or are you instead wanting to know what background-color (or other property) the elements with class foo have?

Comment: As a result, I want to get all the characters (letters, numbers, special chars) that are inside of `.foo { }`. No matter what they are.

Comment: A regex by itself is probably not enough for parsing free-form CSS syntax, only for simple subcases.

Comment: And what about for example: .container > .foo::after {} - i.e. are you interested in all the settings something with class foo might have? Perhaps a bit more explanation of what this is for would clarify the problem a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Most of regex characters are string literals, and a valid string is also a valid regex if it does not include meta characters, so you can use this:

[image]

If you want to get any value for the background color you can use this:

[image]

If you want to get the background color only for .foo you can use a positive lookbehind, like this:

[image]

If you want to match any css rule with any value that comes before a `.foo + space + { + newline + space` you can use something like this:

[image]

Just note, that this regex is specifically designed for your usecase and might need to be generalized for be able to fit in with more examples.

Comment: Looks cool but how to match anything, not just `background-color` ?

Comment: @stahlhammer well, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

If your styles are written in the CSS file, you need to get the computed style. To do so, you can use **getComputedStyle**.

In this case you can get all styles, no needs to use regex.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.foo');
const style = getComputedStyle(element);
console.log('styles', style.padding, style.background, style);
```

```css
.foo {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Text</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my case. I can only operate css stylesheet as a plain string.

Comment: Could you add this detail to your question as it wasn't clear to me that you have a string and need to parse that as opposed to having a style element.